# Select rows where date exist in list. If not found, get next closest date

Tags: postgresql, query, select, syntax

I have been trying to get records from a table by providing a list of dates. But some dates from that list doesn't exist in my table, so in that case I want to get the next closest date.

I used this query that works for a single row, but not for all values in a list.

```
SELECT date FROM table WHERE date > '2022-01-01' ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Example Table:

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-03 |
| 2 | 2022-02-15 |
| 3 | 2022-03-07 |
| 4 | 2022-03-21 |
| 5 | 2022-04-05 |
| 6 | 2022-05-20 |

Expected Results WHERE date IN ('2022-01-01', '2022-02-15', '2022-03-10', '2022-05-20'):

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-03 |
| 2 | 2022-02-15 |
| 4 | 2022-03-21 |
| 6 | 2022-05-20 |

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use a lateral join against a list of dates:

```
select t.*
from (
  values ('2022-01-01'::date), ('2022-02-15'), ('2022-03-10'), ('2022-05-20')
) v(target_date)
  cross join lateral ( 
     select *
     from the_table t2
     where t2.date >= v.target_date
     order by t2.date asc
     limit 1
  ) as t 
;
```

The `values` list is the input dates you are looking for. The derived table is then picking a row where the date is equal or the lowest one that is bigger than the reference value. It essentially runs your statement for one date once for each date in the list.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/u4bAS2Ad)

Comment: Thank you so much!! This does exactly what I wanted. I tested it on 150 dates multiple times and it finished in 2-3ms. I will definitely use this answer as a reference for future problems.

Answer (score 1):

### Technique

You're looking for a pattern known as Most Recent Prior Record. The usual way to look up such a record is to use a range predicate with an aggregate so only one record is returned:

```
select max(dt) from example where dt <= search
```

This gets the highest value of `dt` equal to or less than the value of `search`. PostgreSQL recognizes this pattern and can perform the lookup quickly if an index exists on the column. It also works in the other direction, using `min()` and `=>`.

Using this technique I built the query below. The downside of this technique is that it usually ends up as a correlated subquery, so doing large numbers of lookups is slow. For a handful of lookups it should be plenty fast enough. (It can also be written using a filtered aggregate and `GROUP BY` on the search term.)

### Prerequisites

The example table is called "example", with an `id` and `dt` column. I renamed the date column to `dt` to avoid using a reserved word as a column name.

The query performs well if there is an index on the search column. It should also be unique so we don't have to deal with ties (the query can be modified to handle them if needed). The sample fiddle puts a unique constraint on the `dt` column.

### Query Walkthrough

**Step One**

The first step is to get our most recent prior and successor values for each of our search terms. The search points are input as an array of dates.

```
select (select max(dt) from example where dt <= srch) as prior,
    srch,
    (select min(dt) from example where dt >= srch) as successor
    from unnest(ARRAY['2022-01-01', '2022-02-15', '2022-03-10', '2022-05-20']::date[]) t(srch)
```

| prior | srch | successor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *null* | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-03 |
| 2022-02-15 | 2022-02-15 | 2022-02-15 |
| 2022-03-07 | 2022-03-10 | 2022-03-21 |
| 2022-05-20 | 2022-05-20 | 2022-05-20 |

**Step Two**

The next step is to compute the distance from the search term to the prior and successor terms, to find which is "closest" in the next step. Note that if there is no prior or successor record then NULL is returned.

```
select
    prior,
    srch-prior as prior_days,
    srch,
    successor,
    successor-srch as successor_days
from (
select (select max(dt) from example where dt <= srch) as prior,
    srch,
    (select min(dt) from example where dt >= srch) as successor
    from unnest(ARRAY['2022-01-01', '2022-02-15', '2022-03-10', '2022-05-20']::date[]) t(srch)
) s
```

| prior | prior_days | srch | successor | successor_days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *null* | *null* | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-03 | 2 |
| 2022-02-15 | 0 | 2022-02-15 | 2022-02-15 | 0 |
| 2022-03-07 | 3 | 2022-03-10 | 2022-03-21 | 11 |
| 2022-05-20 | 0 | 2022-05-20 | 2022-05-20 | 0 |

**Step Three**

Using the distance data from the previous step, determine which value is the winner. We must check for NULL values as prior or successor may not exist if there is no such record (off the beginning or end of the table). Of course we also check if the search term itself existed in the table. In the case of a tie we choose the prior date.

```
select
    CASE WHEN prior_days = 0 AND successor_days = 0 THEN srch
    WHEN prior_days < successor_days OR prior_days = successor_days OR successor_days IS NULL THEN prior
    WHEN successor_days < prior_days OR prior_days IS NULL THEN successor
    ELSE NULL
    END as found
from (
select
    prior,
    srch-prior as prior_days,
    srch,
    successor,
    successor-srch as successor_days
from (
select (select max(dt) from example where dt <= srch) as prior,
    srch,
    (select min(dt) from example where dt >= srch) as successor
    from unnest(ARRAY['2022-01-01', '2022-02-15', '2022-03-10', '2022-05-20']::date[]) t(srch)
) s
) r
```

| found |
| --- |
| 2022-01-03 |
| 2022-02-15 |
| 2022-03-07 |
| 2022-05-20 |

**Step Four**

Finally we rearrange our columns and index into the table to extract the row ID numbers. It's a little extra work with the additional subquery, but the lookup uses the same index as before so performance shouldn't be a huge issue (unless you are referencing millions of search terms).

```
select
    (select id from example where dt=found) as id,
    found as date
from (
select
    CASE WHEN prior_days = 0 AND successor_days = 0 THEN srch
    WHEN prior_days < successor_days OR prior_days = successor_days OR successor_days IS NULL THEN prior
    WHEN successor_days < prior_days OR prior_days IS NULL THEN successor
    ELSE NULL
    END as found
from (
select
    prior,
    srch-prior as prior_days,
    srch,
    successor,
    successor-srch as successor_days
from (
select (select max(dt) from example where dt <= srch) as prior,
    srch,
    (select min(dt) from example where dt >= srch) as successor
    from unnest(ARRAY['2022-01-01', '2022-02-15', '2022-03-10', '2022-05-20']::date[]) t(srch)
) s
) r
) p
```

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-03 |
| 2 | 2022-02-15 |
| 3 | 2022-03-07 |
| 6 | 2022-05-20 |

[Demonstration fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gzToRBIC)

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the detailed answer. Performance is really important because I will implement this query in my api. You can expect multiple users to run this query at the same time. And the data can range from 20 rows to 7000. I will give it a try later and do a stress test then I will let you know.

Comment: I tested this query and it took 1.3.s on average without indexing for 32 rows. That won't work for me, as most of the time I have to query for 120 rows or more. But thanks anyways.

Comment: As I said, the index is key to performance.  If you are unable to index the search column (why?) then every search is a table scan.

Comment: I tested all the solutions here and @a_horse_with_no_name solution worked best for me. Even after 150 dates it still took 2-3ms. I assumed if I still did index the search column it won't matter, as lateral join was faster even without index. my sql skills are basic, but I did learn a lot from your query and how important indexing is.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer can be such;

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (date_trunc('month', "date")) 
  id,
  date
FROM date_list
WHERE
    date > '2022-01-01'
ORDER BY
    date_trunc('month', "date"),
    date DESC
```

which basically says `order by date desc` and then output first row, ignore the rest for the same `date_trunc('month', "date")` value

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZEKArQjs) is the fiddle

Comment: This is a good solution, but it doesn't work for me. I need to specify multiple dates. And this query does what I want for the first date only. I still appreciate your help.